# Помощь в уравнении

Tags: c++, математика

нужна помощь в написании кода, который сможет решить данное уравнение.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Лично я вижу здесь формулы, но не виду *уравнения*, которое можно "решить"...

Comment: помогите составить алгоритм для этого выражения

Comment: А в чем именно у вас проблемы? какая функция вам неизвестна?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот решение:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

double beta(double kf_b, double xf_b)
{
    double b = 0;
    b = exp(kf_b - 5.1) + log10(abs(kf_b + xf_b));
    return b;
}

double zet(double xf_z)
{
    double z = 0;
    z = pow(log(abs(pow(2, xf_z) - 1)), 3) - 12.47;
    return z;
}

double qbrt(double qb)
{
    return pow(qb, 1.0/3.0);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    double x = 0.03;
    double k = 4;
    double B = 0;
    B = pow(beta(k, x) + abs(zet(x)), -M_E) + qbrt(abs(zet(x)) + 0.1);
    cout << B << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

`qbrt` - функция кубического корня;

Выдаёт `4.12524`.